# Shake effect in Vue

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, event-listener

I would like to create a shake effect in a vue.js-application. I found an example, with which I can create create a shake effect with JavaScript, but the eventListener can't be used in vue.js- So I do not know how to use this code in vue.js.

Do you have any idea how I could use this animation in vue.js without an eventListener?

Here is the code, which I want to adjust:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./main.css">
    <title>3d Vector Kata</title>

    <style>
        /* Standard syntax */
        @keyframes shake {
            10%, 90% {
                transform: translate3d(-1px, 0, 0);
            }

            20%, 80% {
                transform: translate3d(2px, 0, 0);
            }

            30%, 50%, 70% {
                transform: translate3d(-4px, 0, 0);
            }

            40%, 60% {
                transform: translate3d(4px, 0, 0);
            }
        }

        .apply-shake {
            animation: shake 0.82s cubic-bezier(.36,.07,.19,.97) both;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
<form id="test-form">
    <input type="text" id="test-input">
    <button type="submit" id="submit-button" onclick="shakeAnimation()">Submit</button>
</form>
<script src="./index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

<script>
    const input = document.querySelector("input#test-input");
    const submit = document.querySelector("button#submit-button");

    submit.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        if(input.value === "") {
            submit.classList.add("apply-shake");
        }
    });

    submit.addEventListener("animationend", (e) => {
        submit.classList.remove("apply-shake");
    });

</script>
```

Comment: `but the eventListener can't be used in vue.js` why not? perhaps you're doing it wrong. The code you've shown has nothing to do with vuejs, so how do you know you can't do what you want

Answer (score 2):

The only things that event listener do in your example is to toggle a class.
So you can use conditional class syntax `<button :class="{'apply-shake': shake}">`;

Check on codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/shake-effect-vue-71306745-z912ms?file=/src/App.vue

So you can do something like that:

**Edit: Check [@quadmachine answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71307004/2838586) who use eventListener for animationend instead of setTimeout**

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <button :class="{ 'apply-shake': shake }" @click="shakeAnimation()">
      Shake
    </button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      shake: false,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    shakeAnimation() {
      this.shake = true;
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.shake = false;
      }, 820); // timeout value depending on the duration of the animation
    },
  },
};
</script>

<style>
@keyframes shake {
  10%,
  90% {
    transform: translate3d(-1px, 0, 0);
  }

  20%,
  80% {
    transform: translate3d(2px, 0, 0);
  }

  30%,
  50%,
  70% {
    transform: translate3d(-4px, 0, 0);
  }

  40%,
  60% {
    transform: translate3d(4px, 0, 0);
  }
}

.apply-shake {
  animation: shake 0.82s cubic-bezier(0.36, 0.07, 0.19, 0.97) both;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 2):

Building on @Zecka's solution,  even better to use an event listener instead of a timeout:

https://codesandbox.io/s/shake-effect-vue-71306745-forked-hebrob?file=/src/App.vue:471-754

```
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      shake: false,
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    this.$refs.submit.addEventListener("animationend", () => {
      this.shake = false;
    });
  },
  methods: {
    shakeAnimation() {
      this.shake = true;
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Using event listeners in Vue is not an issue @Florian27, you can target any element in your component easily by adding ref attribute or simply by using `document.querySelector` or even better `this.$el.querySelector` so that it's scoped to your component and then attach an event listener using pure JS.

Comment: Thank you very much for your fast answers. It works very well!

Another question: I have more than one objects. If I click on one object, all objects are being shaked, but I would like to shake only the object, on which I've just clicked on. Do you have an answer to this question too?

My idea is to call just one object with a specific id, but it did not work in my example each time. Maybe you have some better ideas.

Answer (score 0):

```
            //shake.css
            @keyframes shake {
              10%, 90% {
                  transform: translate3d(-1px, 0, 0);
              }
            
              20%, 80% {
                  transform: translate3d(2px, 0, 0);
              }
            
              30%, 50%, 70% {
                  transform: translate3d(-4px, 0, 0);
              }
            
              40%, 60% {
                  transform: translate3d(4px, 0, 0);
              }
            }
            
            .apply-shake {
              animation: shake 0.82s cubic-bezier(.36,.07,.19,.97) both !important;
            }
            
        //shake.js
        import '@/assets/css/shake.css';
        export const shake = app => {
          app.directive('shake', {
            mounted: el => {
              //节流
              let shakeOver = true;
              el.addEventListener(
                'click',
                e => {
                  if (shakeOver) {
                    shakeOver = false;
                    e.target.classList.add('apply-shake');
                    let timer = setTimeout(() => {
                      clearTimeout(timer);
                      e.target.classList.remove('apply-shake');
                      shakeOver = true;
                    }, 820);
                  }
                },
                false
              );
            }
          });
        };
        //main.js
        import { createApp } from 'vue';
        import App from './App.vue';
        
        import {shake} from '@/directives/shake.js'
        
        const app = createApp(App);
        shake(app);
        
        app.mount('#app');
    
    //please use vue3.x

//use example: 
<h1 v-shake>click me</h1>
```